options.platform_name = 'Windows' not working selenium python
chromedriver Version: 125.0.6422.141 (r1287751) (64-bit)
chrome Version: 125.0.6422.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Selenium  version: 4.21.0
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.platform_name = 'Windows 10'
service = ChromeService(executable_path=r'C:\Users\rr\Desktop\TL\chromedriver.exe')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Android 4.4.1; LG-F500L Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/601.44 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/54.0.3656.325 Mobile Safari/602.8'})
browser.set_window_size(393, 851)
url = "https://www.google.com/"
browser.get(url)

When I remove options.platform_name = 'Windows 10' everything works fine but when I try to add the platform name I get this error
Message=Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found

Stacktrace:
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF612EC1F52+60322]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF612E3CEC9]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF612CF7EBA]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF612D7632C]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF612D75451]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF612D770BC]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF612D76F90]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF612D6BFC3]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF612D39617]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF612D3A211]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6131D94AD+3301629]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6132236D3+3605283]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF613219450+3563680]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF612F74326+790390]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF612E4750F]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF612E43404]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF612E43592]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF612E32F9F]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFDB1417344+20]
RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFDB30E26B1+33]`


What documentation or example did you find that shows this exists?

platform_name is mentioned here but the only example i could find is for Ruby see here https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/

why do you think i asked the question if i can just remove the line of code maybe because i need to change the platform name!

The only reference I can find to .platform_name is for Ruby, see here but there's no description of what it does or how to use it.
When I looked in the current docs for Browser Options, I found .platformName. It has a description

This identifies the operating system at the remote-end, fetching the platformName returns the OS name.
In cloud-based providers, setting platformName sets the OS at the remote-end.

but there's no code sample.

does that mean this option is only for ruby?

No? .platform_name is for Ruby, .platformName is for python. Did you read my answer and the link I provided?
